# how to ask sun jersey to return http code other than 200

Tags: java, jersey

```
        @GET
        @Path("/rest/balancequery")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public XXXPojo balanceQuery(@Context UriInfo ui) {
            XXXPojo p = new XXXPojo();
            Boolean fail = this.checkAuthority(ui);
            if(fail) {
                 throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN);
            } 
            else {
                 p = getPojo();
            }
            return p
        }
```

`WebAppliactionException` is described as none-detectable exception, and should return 403. However, the console output does show the trace of exception (I think this means it is detectable), and the client receives 200 as code. It is also mentioned in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102797/how-to-throw-http-204-status-code-using-jersey-framework-in-restful-web-service) "should not return entity". It is impossible for a jersey just return 403 but not a bean when nothing goes wrong. I cannot use glassfish jersey. jdk 1.7 thanks.

```
<!-- jersey -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Jetty -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: There's a concept of exceptionMappers that can map your response to wherever you want. Alternatively, return the response directly and wrap your entity in it: Response.status(MY_STATUS).entity(MY_ENTITY).build()

Comment: @pandaadb I have tried, but nothing changes. WebApplicationException still causes stack printed, and the response status code is still 200.

Comment: @pandaadb finally found the bug in code :)). At the corner there is a catch(Exception e)